# How to bin factor(character values-aphla_numeric) variables with many levels in r

Tags: r

Hope my problem was not clear. I will take up in detail. In my dataset csss having dimension(12782,60), one of the variables is "csa"(which I am interested to deal with) contains 610 levels(Categories/factors). some of the levels contains 1-10 observations(rows) and some contains 800-900 observations.

samples of level(which are aplha-numeric("SFRROC916","SANGEO512","SFRPAL650","HARSPR413")).

My problem is to bring down levels(factors) from 610 to 5 based on number of observations(rows) each level contains.

If number of observation(no of rows): 1-25(observations)="A"-level, 26-60="B"-level, 61-99="C"-level, 100-152="D"-level, >152-"E"-level.

My code is

```
csss$csa<-as.character(csss$csa)
for(i in csss$csa)
{
a1<-nrow(csss[csss$csa==i,])
csss$csa<-ifelse(a1<=25, "A",
                ifelse((a1>=26 & a1<=60), "B",
                       ifelse((a1>=61 & a1<=99), "C",
                             ifelse((a1>=100 & a1<=152), "D", "E"))))
}
```

I am end up in having only one level with the above code. Help me to resolve. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of using a loop with `==`, use `%in%`  ie. `n1 <- sum(csss$csa %in% z); c("A", "B")[(n1 <=200) + 1]`  Also, it is not clear whether you want to do this on the whole column  or the `levels`.    If it is the latter, do `n1 <- sum(levels(csss$csa)%in% z)`

Comment: Please comment for the above code. The question had been changed to explain in detail.

Comment: you can check the updated solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this in `base R` with

```
n1 <- sum(csss$csa %in% z)
csss$new.csa <- c("A", "B")[(n1 <=200) + 1]
```

if the condition is based on the `levels` on the 'csa'

```
n1 <- sum(levels(csss$csa) %in% z)
```

---

If this is based on the number of observations per each group, a `base R` option would be

```
nm1 <- names(which(table(csss$csa) > 200))
df1$new.csa <- c("B", "A")[(csss$csa %in% nm1) + 1]
```

#### Update

Based on the update in the OP's post, it can be done with `cut` or `findInterval`

```
tbl <- table(csss$csa)
nm1 <- as.character(cut(tbl, breaks = c(-Inf, 25, 60, 99, 152, Inf), 
           labels = LETTERS[1:5]))
csss$new.csa <- setNames(nm1, names(tbl))[csss$csa]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
csss <- data.frame(csa = sample(c("SFRROC916","SANGEO512","SFRPAL650","HARSPR413", 
   "HARSPR412", 
       "SFROC197", "SANGEO514", "SGFG0984", "SAND942"), 
 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.02, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
     0.4, 0.4)), col2 = rnorm(1000), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: This code worked:                                                                                                   tbl <- table(csss$csa)
nm1 <- as.character(cut(tbl, breaks = c(-Inf, 25, 60, 99, 152, Inf), 
           labels = LETTERS[1:5]))
csss$new.csa <- setNames(nm1, names(tbl))[csss$csa]....Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The expression `x <- nrow(...)` returns a scalar (the number of rows of your subsetted data frame). Then `ifelse(x > 200, 'A', 'B')` will also return a scalar, so all entries in the `csa` column will be replaced with that number. I am guessing you want to do the following: Replace `csa` so that instead of 610 possible values it only contains two, `A`, or `B`, depending on the number of observations of each original value ('A' when there are more than 200 observations). Is that right?

Try

```
library(dplyr) 
new.csss <- csss %>% 
    group_by(csa) %>%
    mutate(new.csa = if_else(n() > 200, 'A', 'B'))
```

The column `new.csa` will be either `'A'` or `'B'` depending on the number of rows with the corresponding value of `csa`.